# Procrun on Windows 2012 Server with too long classpath-parameter defect report

Tags: java, windows, service, server, procrun

I have a problem with procrun on Windows 2012 Server. 
The classpath is too long(about 12k signs). Procrun give a defect report: "The selected data area is too small". So is there a posibility to change the length of the classpath? Or what should i do? Maybe you have a solution for this problem. I would be really happy :D

Best regards!